# Why do some journals ask if there is someone who you do not wish to use as a referee?

Tags: peer-review

I have noticed that sometimes when you submit an article to a journal it will ask if there is someone in particular who you do not want to referee the paper.

I was wondering what the reason for this option was.  Is it simply to avoid a conflict of interest or if you really do not get on with the person to the point where you do not wish them to review something you have written?  If you put someone down as someone you do not want to be a referee, will the journal think you are scared of that person's critical appraisal of the document and actually send it to that person or will they genuinely avoid sending it to that person for review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that sending the paper to a person you indicated that you didn't want as a referee after they ask for that information would be unethical. No reputable journal would (or should) do anything like that.

I don't know precisely why any particular journal has any particular policy, but perhaps they have just had enough experience with people making such suggestions on their own, that they now make it routine to ask. It is a courtesy, nothing more.

But the author(s) can have any motive they please here, from "I don't trust the person" to "I'm keeping this private from them for a while". If they don't ask for a reason, don't provide one.

Answer (score 4):

This happens when the author (or applicant in the case of a grant) believes that some likely referee might not act fairly for some personal reasons.  In my experience this is usually some history in these disputes. There might also be conflicts of interests.

Often there is guidance on who can be excluded, and the person must provide some measure (sometimes merger) of justification.